# TypeScript won't compile mp3 audio file

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, audio, avaudioplayer

#### Usecase

I am developing a **Node JS CLI** written in **TypeScript**. I need to **play a notification sound** on the successful completion of the CLI tasks. So, I've kept the audio file locally in a folder named **assets**.

#### Issue

I'm unable to compile the audio file along with the entire app in the final build. I'm using `tsc -p .` command which compiles all the files in the app except the audio file.

#### Folder Structure

Below is the folder structure of the app.

```
|_src
  |_assets
    |_notification.mp3
  |_scripts
  |_utils
  |_templates
  |_message
  |_index.ts
```

#### TSConfig File

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                         
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "resolveJsonModule":true,                
    "declaration": false,                    
    "outDir": "lib",                         
    "downlevelIteration": true,              
    "strict": true,                          
    "esModuleInterop": true,                 
    "skipLibCheck": true,                    
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true 
  },
  "exclude": ["./src/scripts/minify.ts", "my-app"]
}
```

**Note:** Please don't suggest using a file storage service as I need to make sure the tool works offline.

Comment: Can you `cp` the assets folder to your outDir after TypeScript finishes compiling? `tsc` isn't made for copying files or compiling mp3 files.

Comment: Copying assets/files manually is never a solution. If TypeScript Compiler is not meant for that, I guess I'll have to choose a packager such as WebPack.